# Javascript undefined error on last iteration

Tags: javascript, string, undefined

When looping through this string, the alert prints out test 4 times (correctly) but then also prints "undefined" at the end. How do I make it doesn't return undefined.

This returns - undefinedCAFE ::

```
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));


function match(string, pattern) {

    var patternUpperCase = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var stringUpperCase = string.toUpperCase();
    var stringConcatenate;
    var answer;

    for (var i = 0; i < patternUpperCase.length; i++) {
        if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) != undefined) {
            if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) >= 'A' && patternUpperCase.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                stringConcatenate += patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
                alert("test");
            }
        }
    }
    return stringConcatenate;
}
```

Comment: When adding return stringConcatenate; The returned value is - undefinedCAFE

Answer (score 2):

The `match` function doesn't have a return statement, so it returns `undefined`. This means that

```
alert(match("abcdef","CAfe"));
```

will always show an alert of "undefined" at least once. To not show the alert, call the function without using `alert`:

```
match("abcdef","CAfe");
```

Alternatively you can make the function return something, such as `stringConcatenate`, which would be computed for no reason otherwise.

Comment: aka, you need to have `return stringConcatenate;` at the end of your function `match`

Comment: Oh so that's what the function is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));

    function match(string, pattern) {

    var patternUpperCase = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var stringUpperCase = string.toUpperCase();
    var stringConcatenate;
    var answer;
    var i = 0;


    for (var i = 0; i < patternUpperCase.length; i++) {
        if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) != undefined) {
            if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) >= 'A' && patternUpperCase.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                stringConcatenate = stringConcatenate + patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
                alert("test");
            }
        }
    }
   return stringConcatenate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last "undefined" valie is result of your function:

```
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sava/Dw7jm/